# How to redirect error message in Sublime Text to a file

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I am using sublime to write code in C++. I use the following build system to execute my code which works fine.

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt>output.txt"],
"selector":"source.cpp",
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path"
}
```

However in case of a segmentation fault I don't reveive any error message in the console. Is there a way to redirect all error messages in a file say 'error.txt' just like output.

Answer (score 0):

The following should redirect STDERR to `error.txt`. `2>` is the proper shell redirector to use.

```json
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt>output.txt2>error.txt"],
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/redirecting-error-command-prompt) for an explanation.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I tried this build command. However I stopped receiving output messages as well. 

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt","2>error.txt>output.txt"],
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

This build command wil work on sublime text.